# Setting a constraint for all properties of a domain object?

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, constraints, grails-orm

Is there a way to set a constraint for all properties of a grails domain object?

I want to set `nullable: true` for a class, essentially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can. From what I can find, your only options are:

1. Specify the constraint per property in the `static constraints` closure on the domain class
2. Use a [shared constraint or default constraint](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/Usage.html), configured in Config.groovy

I dug around through [DefaultConstraintEvaluator.groovy](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-core/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/validation/DefaultConstraintEvaluator.java) to see if there was some undocumented way to maybe use a class or property name in the `grails.gorm.default.constraints` configuration, but didn't find any.

Perhaps you could submit a JIRA feature request to allow configuring default constraints per-class (by adding to the existing default constraints DSL).